# Angular 13: Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers

Tags: angular, pagespeed

I have an Angular 13 app configured for SSR and when I run the lighthouse for Google PageSpeed I get the following warning:

```
Avoid serving legacy JavaScript to modern browsers
```

I do have configured the browserlist as per the documentation / generation of the site:

```
# This file is used by the build system to adjust CSS and JS output to support the specified browsers below.
# For additional information regarding the format and rule options, please see:
# https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#queries

# For the full list of supported browsers by the Angular framework, please see:
# https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

# You can see what browsers were selected by your queries by running:
#   npx browserslist

last 1 Chrome version
last 1 Firefox version
last 2 Edge major versions
last 2 Safari major version
last 2 iOS major versions
Firefox ESR
```

How can this be fixed? My `tsconfig.json` is:

```
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

The `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

I don't know if there is another setting to configure to get this sorted.